# Is it possible to create Spark application with spark-avro datasource and execute it via 'java -jar'

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, avro

I have a java application which is using spark for accessing data from various datasources (hadoop, local filesystem, ..) in various formats (json, avro, ...).

```
   SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("Spark app")
        .master("local")
        .getOrCreate();
    Dataset<Row> dataset = spark
        .read()
        .format(FORMAT)) // avro, json, ...
        .load(FILEPATH);
```

I am able to create fat jar and run it via "java -jar". There is no problem as long as I am using JSON as "FORMAT". But if "JSON" is replaced by "AVRO" then it throws exception that `Failed to find data source: AVRO. Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4`. If I run it directly in (IDE) than all works even with avro but if is it in jar then works only JSON.

I know that avro is external datasource to spark and that it has to be somehow added to spark but dont know how and if is it even possible to run such application only via `java -jar app.jar -param -param1`

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in maven build plugin. I was using `maven-assembly-plugin`, but when I replaced it by `maven-shade-plugin` then everything works.